# Проблемы с кодировкой

Tags: python, кодировка

Доброе время суток, решил изучить Python и тут же - рогами в стену. ))

Написал прогу по книге

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from Tkinter import*
class But_print:
    def __init__(self):
        self.but=Button(root,text="Печатать")
        #self.but["text"]="Print"
        self.but.bind("<Button-1>", self.printer)
        self.but.pack()
        self.but=Label(root,text="Это метка! \n Из двух строк.", font="Arial 18")
        self.but.pack()
    def printer(self,event): 
        print ("Как всегда 'Hello World'")
root=Tk()
lab=Label(root,text="Это метка! \n Из двух строк.", font="Arial 18")
obj=But_print()
root.mainloop()
```

Но, когда нажимаю кнопку "Печатать", после запуска проги, получаю:

> `>>> ================================ RESTART ================================`
> `>>>`
> `РљР°Рє РІСЃРµРіРґР° 'Hello World'`
> `РљР°Рє РІСЃРµРіРґР° 'Hello World'`
> `>>>`

В книге пока не нашел ответов. )))

Comment: Где запускаете? Если в виндовой консоли, то она печатает в cp866 по умолчанию.

Comment: По умолчанию, у меня

    # -*- coding: cp1251 -*-

Ваш вариант не подходит)))

Comment: Вписав cp866, поучил на кнопках пустые квадраты, а текст печатается каракулями.))) Скорее всего в python 3... все работает.
Я же, по рекомендации сайта для начинающих установил python 2.7.2

Answer (score 6):

Используйте юникодные строки (`myvar = u"Это строка"`)
Ну и сам файл скрипта должен быть в UTF-8.

Comment: Благодарю за помощ, все заработало как надо)))

Comment: Пожалуйста. Ответ примите:)

Answer (score 0):

В print можно, также, добавить encoding='utf-8'